# Pointers help for c

Tags: c

I am new to programming and I was wondering if someone could help me out. My error says

[Error] cannot convert 'float**' to 'float*' for argument '1' to 'void acceptDailyandConvert(float*, float*, float*)'

and this is my code.

Thanks so much in advance.

```
void acceptDailyandConvert(float*, float*, float*);

int
main()
{
    
    // VARIABLE DECLARATION
    float *dailyRate, *hourlyRate, *minRate;
    
    // FUNCTION CALLING
    acceptDailyandConvert(&dailyRate, &hourlyRate, &minRate);
}

void
acceptDailyandConvert(float *dailyRate, float *hourlyRate, float *minRate){
    
    // accepts daily rate, converts into hourly rate and rate per minute (pointer variables)
    
    printf("Enter your daily rate: ");
    scanf("%f", &dailyRate);
    
    // hourly rate is 1/8th of daily rate
    hourlyRate = dailyRate * 0.125;
    // minute rate is 1/60th of hourly rate
    minRate = hourlyRate * 0.02;
    
    printf("\n \t Hourly Rate: %.2f ", hourlyRate);
    printf("\n \t Rate per minute: %.2f ", minRate);
    
}
```

Im not really sure how to go about it, ive tried mixing around the ampersand and the asterisk (Totally clueless).

Comment: You have a lot more problems than that, for example `dailyRate * 0.125` is utter nonsense as well.

Comment: What book are you learning from?

Comment: It seems the three variables in `main()` should not be pointers.

Comment: im not using a book at the moment

Comment: "im not using a book at the moment" That's your problem right here.

Comment: @Blindy - the `dailyRate * 0.125` is super awkward but not nonsense; it's just dividing by 8 hours.

Comment: @SteveFriedl, you can't multiply or divide a pointer. Or well, *we* can't, you seem to be able to for some reason.

Comment: @Blindy - oh wow, duh: good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh yes, the pain of learning c pointers!!

This is one way to do it...

```
#include <stdio.h>

void acceptDailyandConvert(float*, float*, float*);

int
main()
{

// VARIABLE DECLARATION
    float dailyRate, hourlyRate, minRate;

// FUNCTION CALLING
    acceptDailyandConvert(&dailyRate, &hourlyRate, &minRate);
}

void acceptDailyandConvert(float *dailyRate, float *hourlyRate, float *minRate){

// accepts daily rate, converts into hourly rate and rate per minute (pointer variables)

    printf("Enter your daily rate: ");
    scanf("%f", dailyRate);

// hourly rate is 1/8th of daily rate
    hourlyRate[0] = dailyRate[0] * 0.125;
// minute rate is 1/60th of hourly rate
    minRate[0] = hourlyRate[0] * 0.02;

    printf("\n \t Hourly Rate: %.2f ", hourlyRate[0]);
    printf("\n \t Rate per minute: %.2f ", minRate[0]);

}
```

Comment: thanks so much! if you dont mind explaining, what are the [0] 's for? Sorry im just starting out and havent learned it in uni yet

Comment: It so the compiler knows you mean the value not the reference. when you allocate a pointer, it can be the start of an array of many values of that data type.

Comment: By the way, *0.02 is 1/50 not 1/60th.

Comment: I don't like `hourlyRate[0]`. It's a pointer, just dereference it with `*hourlyRate`. Introducing array syntax may do more harm than good.

Comment: Fair point, but could you explain how it could 'do more harm than good'? Thanks.

Comment: Simply because in C the relationship between arrays and pointers confuses many people, so I wouldn't mix them. Sometimes you need pointers when working with arrays, and you can't avoid them, but in general you don't need arrays when you work with pointers, so I wouldn't introduce them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pointers, initialize them first, then pass the pointers to the function not the reference (remove the `&`). To access the pointer value use `*`, eg. `*hourlyRate`.